# How to detect a moment when ListView item becomes ActiveView (going off-screen)

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

According to concept of recycling items mechanism in ListView.

[image]

I want to know, actually, how i can detect a moment when a `View` **going off-screen**.

---

I explain why.

In most cases `ListView` have a custom 
`Adapter(? extends ArrayAdapter / ? extends BaseAdapter, etc.).`

`getView(...)` method allows to manipulate visibility and content of views (text,bitmaps,drawables,etc.)

And in some cases i need to launch a separate Thread which `doing` background work, and after that update UI. Actually - using AsyncTask.

When i have many items in `ListView` each call of **getView** will be produced start a new `Thread`. I need to cancel them if `View` is no more longer present on the screen. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can override [onDetachedFromWindow](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/view/View.html#onDetachedFromWindow()) for the view.This will let you know when the view is going off-screen.The docs says:

> protected void **onDetachedFromWindow ()**
>
> Added in API level 1 This is called when the view is detached from a
>   window. At this point it no longer has a surface for drawing.

See Also
onAttachedToWindow()