# Picasso repeats images

Tags: android, picasso

So, I'm using Picasso in a `Listview`. Below is the relevant section of my adapter. Each item has an image and a title. I attempt to download the image for the item and if the URL for the item is an empty string, I uses a local image as a placeholder. Everything works fine, aside from having an image just off the screen.

Let's say that the screen shows four items, all with image URLs. The fifth item, just below what can be seen on the screen has no image URL and therefore should display the default placeholder image. The issue is that when I scroll down, the fifth image displays the image for the fourth item. If I scroll the fifth item off the screen and come back, it reverts to the placeholder. I don't seem to have this problem anywhere else on the list.

What am I doing wrong?

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.staff_directory_list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.StaffDirectoryName);
            holder.image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.StaffDirectoryImage);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
            holder.title.setText(mStaffMembers.get(position).getTitle());
            String imageUrl = mStaffMembers.get(position).getImage();

            try {
                Picasso.with(context).cancelRequest(holder.image);
                Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl)
                                .placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder)
                                .error(R.drawable.image_placeholder)
                                .centerCrop()
                                .fit()
                                .tag(context)
                                .into(holder.image);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                    Picasso.with(context).cancelRequest(holder.image);
                    Picasso.with(context)
                                .load(R.drawable.image_placeholder)
                                .into(holder.image);
                }
            }
        return v;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are seeing the recycled view. The 4th item will not be deleted by `ListView` and as you scroll will be brought back to you. And because you hadn't take care of removing the image when the 4th item was scrolled off the screen, this image will still be there.

What you have to do, is to refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33403478/1083957). Reset the source of the `ImageView` as soon as your `ListView`'s row is being scrolled off the screen (i.e. "recycled"). [`onDetachedFromWindow()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDetachedFromWindow()) is the appropriate callback.